# GeoDjango Polygon Field ParseException

Tags: django, gis, openlayers, openstreetmap, geodjango

I am using GeoDjango to display a form where a user can select an area on a map and name it.

I have the following model

```
import django.contrib.gis.db.models as models    
class Area(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  area_target = models.PolygonField(default='POLYGON EMPTY')
```

And this form

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms
class AreaForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=160)
  area_target = forms.PolygonField(srid=4326, required=False, widget=forms.OSMWidget(attrs={'map_width': 600, 'map_height': 500}))
```

The form is displayed correctly and I can select an area using the map widget, but I get the following error message when I submit the form:

> GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Expected 'Z', 'M', 'ZM', 'EMPTY' or '('
>   but encountered : ')'
>
> GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Expected 'Z', 'M', 'ZM', 'EMPTY' or '('
>   but encountered : ')'
>
> Error creating geometry from value 'SRID=900913;POLYGON()' (Error
>   encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function
>   "GEOSWKTReader_read_r".)

This is how the polygon is drawn:
[image: Polygon drawn with OSM Widget]

As you can see in the debug output there are no values for the edges of the polygon.

I am using Django 1.9.4, a postgres 9.5.1.0 DB with postgis extension and geos 3.5 as geometry backend.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: YOu haven't shown how you are creating an Area object.

Comment: The area object should be created by drawing a polygon. I added a screenshot...

Comment: please open the javascript console and show if any errors show up

Comment: I don't get any errors in the javascript console.

Comment: This is an OSM issue more than a GeoDjango issue is what I feel. Can I suggest changing one of the tags to open street map so that it will come to the attention of experts of that topic.

Comment: Sure, i changed the tags Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`POLYGON(())` is invalid [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), and will throw a ParseException as shown.

Try `POLYGON EMPTY` to create an empty Polygon geometry.

I'm not familiar with GeoDjango, but perhaps NULL/None is an option too.